# obj1 *= obj2 VS. obj1 = obj1 * obj2 in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Assuming that i've implemented `*=`, `=` and `*` operators overloading, which will you prefer to use complexity wise?
Thanks.

Comment: arrh here we go again , another "VS." question

Comment: I don't mind the "vs"ness. I mind the vagueness. "Complexity-wise"? What do those operators _do_? Care to share?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think it's a good question...

Comment: _Could_ be worse, could be `i++` vs `i += 1` vs `i = i + 1` :-)

Comment: There are good explanations in Scott Meyer's *Effective C++* and *More Effective C++*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I’d usually implement `operator *` in terms of `operator *=` and a copy, there is no reason ever to prefer `operator *`.

The normal implementation of `operator *` (and `+`, `-`, `/` etc.) should usually look as follows:

```
T operator *(T const& left, T const& right) {
    T result = left;
    return result *= right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are NOT complex for simple operations like the one you have specified. But, for longer expressions, *= can make things more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented them normally, then prefer `*=`.  The other way will require making a copy, then applying `*=` to it, then assigning it back.

Comment: good point. However, with the new c++11's move semantic's, that's not much of an overhead.

Comment: @Eddie: All the little things add up.  And since using `x*=y` in place of `x=x*y` costs you nothing in terms of performance, personal productivity or code readability, there is absolutely no reason to prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The = and * separate implementations are more useful. It allows a * b * c * d type expressions. However consider the overhead of additional copies being created, as noted by Benjamin Lindley.